# Как убрать определенные элементы из двумерной коллекции наиболее коротко и эффективно?

Tags: c#

Дан список

```
var spisok = new List<List<string>>();
```

Вопрос, если получилось так, что он содержит пустые списки, то как их удалить все разом, уменьшив тем самым размер списка? Пустой список в данном случае значит, что

```
spisok[index1].Count==1 && spisok[index1][index2] == ""
```

Пробовал идти вложенными циклами, но это кидает исключения OutOfRange, так как при удалении размер списка уменьшается

Comment: Вы пишете "Пробовал идти вложенными циклами, но это кидает исключения OutOfRange". В таких случаях есть "стандартный" способ - перебирать список в обратном порядке, т.е. от конца к началу :) Естественно, это касается циклов `for`

Comment: @velial, `for` и в прямом направлении должен работать, если вовремя декрементиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ещё как вариант

```
spisok.RemoveAll(s => (s.Count == 1 && s[0] == ""));
```

Но лучше всё-таки выучить LINQ, без него никуда.

Comment: Но скобки лишние :)

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так:

```
spisok = spisok.Where(s => !(s.Count == 1 && s[0] == "")).ToList();
```

с ненулевым `index2` у вас все равно будет падать, так что вы скорее всего хотели именно первый элемент в каждом списке проверить на ""

Comment: можете пояснить, что вы сделали? Where - студия не знает, что это и подчеркивает

Comment: @IWProgrammer добавьте `using System.Linq;` в начале файла

Comment: а возможно ли это сделать без Linq?

Comment: @IWProgrammer, можно, добавьте код метода Where в проект, он предельно прост

Comment: @Андрей, он не работает. И ошибки не пишет, но и не удаляет пустые строки

Comment: @IWProgrammer, добавьте в текст вопроса пример входных данных и что вы ожидаете получить на выходе

Comment: @IWProgrammer я же не придумывал условие за вас :). просто взять и поставить условие в where с отрицанием - вполне хороший и простой способ. гораздо лучше, чем удалять элементы из list (удаление - дорогая операция)

Comment: @Андрей, входные данные - прото список списков, в котором некоторый ячейках есть пустые списки (так как список строк, то там лежит пустая строка), надо убрать подобные ячейки

Comment: @IWProgrammer, всё же дополните ответ простым набором входных данных и ожидаемого вывода, что очевидно для одного - не очевидно для другого, но судя по тому как вы описали требования - этот ответ вам должен подойти

Comment: @IWProgrammer: А вы случайно не забыли присвоить? Не просто `spisok.Where(...)`, а `spisok = spisok.Where(...)`.